# What is a better way to visualize data when some groups have multiple individuals but others have only one individual?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to plot mutation rate for different genes for species that belongs to five subgenera(groups). For some of the groups there are multiple species but for others there are only one species with in the group. Boxplot using ggplot2 in R works ok but it's very hard to distinguish the different groups and especially the groups with only one species.

Any recommendation on what type of graph would be better in this scenario?

Here's the result of boxplot:
[image: png of boxplot using ggplot2]

and the code I used to get the boxplot is:

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x=dS, y = Genes, color = Subgenus))
```

Here's what my data looks like (only for first gene):

```
df <- tibble(Subgenus =c("Adenia", "Astrophea", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Deidamiodies", "Deidamiodies", "Deidamiodies", "Deidamiodies", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Tetrapathea"), Species = c("A.mannii", "P.pittieri", "P.affinis", "P.auriculata_FG", "P.auriculata_S", "P.biflora", "P.filipes", "P.jatusachensis", "P.lutea", "P.microstipula", "P.misera", "P.rufa", "P.suberosa", "P.tenuiloba", "P.arbelaezii", "P.cirrhifolia", "P.contracta", "P.obovata", "P.actinia", "P.cincinnata", "P.edulis", "P.foetida", "P.laurifolia", "P.ligularis", "P.menispermifolia", "P.nitida", "P.oerstedii", "P.quadrangularis", "P.retipetala", "P.serratifolia", "P.serratodigitata", "P.vitifolia", "P.tetrandra"), Genes = c("atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA"), dS = c("0.2929", "0.2596", "0.3069", "0.3178", "0.3138", "0.3014", "0.3009", "0.3293", "0.292", "0.2894", "0.32", "0.3154", "0.334", "0.339", "0.28", "0.2946", "0.2841", "0.2947", "0.2959", "0.3153", "0.2939", "0.3095", "0.2988", "0.2964", "0.3177", "0.2928", "0.3145", "0.2933", "0.314", "0.3037", "0.2995", "0.2981", "0.2807"))
```

Comment: Perhaps an old-fashioned table that you can sort would be more appropriate rather than an image. There's more information in this graphic than _some_ (read: most) people could reasonably interpret. Another possibility is to categorize the genes into groupings or themes, then facet on that categorization.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. A table would be good but might be very hard when I have values for many genes, perhaps the gene categorizes would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider making a heatmap: you can use Genes and Species as columns or rows (subject to constraints imposed by the dimensions of the real dataset), then double-encode dS with colour and text. This layout allows for easy grouping of species into subgenera.

#### Your dataset, expanded with meaningless data to illustrate the point

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(Subgenus =c("Adenia", "Astrophea", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Decaloba", "Deidamiodies", "Deidamiodies", "Deidamiodies", "Deidamiodies", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Passiflora", "Tetrapathea"), Species = c("A.mannii", "P.pittieri", "P.affinis", "P.auriculata_FG", "P.auriculata_S", "P.biflora", "P.filipes", "P.jatusachensis", "P.lutea", "P.microstipula", "P.misera", "P.rufa", "P.suberosa", "P.tenuiloba", "P.arbelaezii", "P.cirrhifolia", "P.contracta", "P.obovata", "P.actinia", "P.cincinnata", "P.edulis", "P.foetida", "P.laurifolia", "P.ligularis", "P.menispermifolia", "P.nitida", "P.oerstedii", "P.quadrangularis", "P.retipetala", "P.serratifolia", "P.serratodigitata", "P.vitifolia", "P.tetrandra"), Genes = c("atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA", "atpA"), dS = c("0.2929", "0.2596", "0.3069", "0.3178", "0.3138", "0.3014", "0.3009", "0.3293", "0.292", "0.2894", "0.32", "0.3154", "0.334", "0.339", "0.28", "0.2946", "0.2841", "0.2947", "0.2959", "0.3153", "0.2939", "0.3095", "0.2988", "0.2964", "0.3177", "0.2928", "0.3145", "0.2933", "0.314", "0.3037", "0.2995", "0.2981", "0.2807"))
i <- 1
while (i < 5) { i <- i + 1; df <- rbind(df, df)}
for (x in 1:16) { df[1*x:33*x, 'Genes'] <- paste0('atpA', x)}
```

#### Plot heatmap, you can't make meaningful comparisons if dS is character

```
df$dS <- as.numeric(df$dS)
ggplot(data = df, aes(y = Species, x = Genes)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = dS)) + 
    geom_text(aes(group = Subgenus, label = dS), size = 3) +
    facet_grid(Subgenus ~., scales = 'free') + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It helps to visualize much better than boxplot. I have never done heat map before. I will definitely play around with heat map plot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If the emphasis is on comparing mutation rate (I assume that's `dS`), consider using that to define your sort order instead of sorting genes alphabetically.

It might also be useful to think and experiment with which comparisons you want to give visual prominence to: is it the difference in dS across species, or across subgenus, or across genes? I'd suggest those be encoded with position or length and arranged visually to be adjacent and on a common scale.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = dS, 
               y = Species %>% fct_reorder(dS), 
               color = Subgenus)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Genes) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  labs(y="") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. Sorting out by dS values makes the graph way better as you have shown. However, I have 68 genes right now, so there will many graphs per gene for dS values if I try that method. I ran linear mixed model and found variation is mostly associated with gene types and subgenus. So perhaps grouping by gene type and visualizing them would be better. Thanks again for your comment.